# spatie / laravel-translatable Fields Translating

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-translatable

I'm using `spatie/laravel-translatable` package for translating some fields in my model.
I have model [model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KElM.png) where declated that 'title' field is translatable attribute.
When I getting list of my Model data in controller [controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrW0h.png)  this field is not translated and gives all possible translations in `json` format [result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PshaE.png) (this package requires that translatable fields must be `json` type). But then I getting title from my model [getting title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NZST.png) its gives correct translated result [correct result of title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrC7r.png)

I need to when I getting all data of my model every translatable fields was translated like :

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "title":"Tbilisi"
    "country_id": 4
},
```

Please help if it possible to get data like this. thanks.